Given an array that has a max-heap of unknown size, find heap size
I'm given an n sized array that houses a max-heap in it's first x elements (x is unknown). After those x elements, each element has value of infinity. My task is to find x in log(x) time complexity.
For example, if n=2^100 and x happens to be equal to 30, then I need to perform 5 operations, and not 100.
So far the only method I thought of was to go down the heap (either only to left sons or right sons) until I go out of bounds or reach a node whose next child's value is infinity,
Afterwards I would go linearly from the current node till I find x.
However the linear progression I performed is of O(x) time complexity and thus this method yields O(x).
Maybe I didn't search hard enough, but I haven't seen solutions to this online yet. Any help would be really appreciated.

No, you can't possibly have an array of length 2^100. Most people don't have any grasp of just how big numbers like 2^100 are. Current computers have operations in the range of nanoseconds. Let's be generous, and assume you have somehow acquired a computer with a picosecond clock cycle. If you could allocate and initialize one element per picosecond, then 2^100 elements would take 2^100  / 1E12 / 3600 / 24 / 365.25 years. Divide that by 14E9, the estimated age of the universe, and you'd complete allocation in ~2.87 times the current age of the universe, and could then start your search.

Use an exponentially increasing index corresponding to going down the left side of the heap while the values are not infinite/the heap property holds. Then use lower/upper bound on the last row (now you know the size)?

Keep doubling the index you check until you get to the first infinity. Say this happens at index 2^k.
I.e., check indices in this order: 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ..., 2^(k-1), 2^k. We stop at 2^k because arr[2^k] == infinity.
Then we do binary search between 2^(k-1) and 2^k to find the index x.
This has O(log x) complexity.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think the binary search between 2^(k-1) and 2^k would result in O(log x) complexity. There could be a case where only one element of x exists in 2^(k-1) and 2^k while all others are infinity. In that case (pretending the whole array is a binary tree) we are practically running a binary search on n-dependent number of elements, which would result in O(log n) time complexity.

@razml consider yourself corrected. 2^(k-1) < x < 2^k so k is O(log(x)).

Thanks a bunch! took some time to figure out the binary search is dependent on x and not n, but it's definitely the case!
